# Why Flask writes logs into my logging log?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, logging

I in proccess of creating simple app which i run in debug mode in flask.
I decided to use logging to write logs.

```
import logging
dlog = logging
dlog.basicConfig(filename='app.log', format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
                 datefmt='[%Y-%m-%d | %H:%M:%S]', level=logging.INFO)
    ...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='localhost', port='8002')
```

But I've discovered that in app.log(and my app is is not called "app.py") Flask writes own logs in addition to mine.
like:

```
[2020-05-01 | 21:36:04]  * Running on http://localhost:8002/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
[2020-05-01 | 21:36:04]  * Restarting with stat
[2020-05-01 | 21:36:05]  * Debugger is active!
[2020-05-01 | 21:36:05]  * Debugger PIN: 290-968-029
[2020-05-01 | 21:36:15] 127.0.0.1 - - [01/May/2020 21:36:15] "[37mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
[2020-05-01 | 21:36:15] 127.0.0.1 - - [01/May/2020 21:36:15] "[36mGET /static/js/main.js HTTP/1.1[0m" 304 -
```

Why does this happening and how can I separate flask logging from my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `logging.basicConfig` configures the root logger. All created loggers [propagate log messages to their parents](https://docs.python.org/3.8/howto/logging.html#logging-flow) unless they are explicitly told not to:

```
app.logger.propagate = False
```

Disabling the logger is also an option:

```
app.logger.disabled = True
```

or setting less verbose mode

```
app.logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Making flask log only to another file is more complicated. You have to remove `StreamHandler` and create `FileHandler` and `Formatter` manually. `logging` module gives you a lot of flexibility, but can be cumberstone:

```
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes
formatter = logging.Formatter("{asctime:s} {name} [{levelname}] {filename}:{lineno} {msg}", style="{")
file_handler = logging.FileHandler("flask.log")
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
# set log level threshold for this handler
file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# flask creates StreamHandler for you, if you don't want that
# just set handlers to empty list
app.logger.handlers = []
app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
# set log level on the flask logger
app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# don't propagate to parent logger (logging.root) to not duplicate
# the logs if you're handling log messages in root logger
app.logger.propagate = False

app.logger.info("spanish iniquisition")

# flask.log:
# 2020-05-02 09:12:31,631 t [INFO] t.py:16 spanish iniquisition
```

Comment: Thank you, but to be honest I still can not understand how to separate logging. For example if i want to write flask logs in "flask.log" and my work flow in "mylog.log" How can i redirect flask logs to another log file?

Comment: Your answer was helpful but did not solved problem. However it's also about my incorrect question. Because AS I figured out I had problem with wsgi logs